# Protractor Test Randomly Failing with Error "Failed: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:32572"

Tags: jenkins, protractor

My Protractor test randomly fails with error . :

```
Failed: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:32572 
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\jenkins\workspace\QA-E2E\automation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:238:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
From: Task: WebDriver.navigate().to(data:text/html,<html></html>)
    at Driver.schedule (C:\jenkins\workspace\QA-E2E\automation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:807:17)
    at Navigation.to (C:\jenkins\workspace\QA-E2E\automation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1133:25)
    at Driver.get (C:\jenkins\workspace\QA-E2E\automation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:988:28)
    at C:\jenkins\workspace\QA-E2E\automation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:675:32
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\jenkins\workspace\QA-E2E\automation\SeleniumFramework\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
```

Node version : v12.14.1, 
npm version : 6.13.4, 
protractor version: 5.4.2, 
webdriver-manager version:  12.1.6

Note : I am also using async/await in my test.

Comment: are you using direct connect? what is your chrome version and chromedriver?

Comment: Yes, I am suing `directConnect: true,` `chrome version :  Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)`  `chromedriver_80.0.3987.16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening to me when I have more chromedriver.exe processes in background. 
Terminate all processes in background or restart the computer and you should not see this error.

Comment: I did not see any chromedriver.exe running, but I have many chrome.exe running.

Comment: That is what you need to terminate all chrome.exe are driven by the chromedriver. Close all and if is not working restart the pc (that will end all processes) and run the script.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a problem some time ago when this error was specific to a some chromedriver, which had to resolved from selenium side. Since chromedriver 80 is a brand new version, I assume it's just a temporary bug which will be fixed some time soon

Meanwhile, you can try the solution that I used for a while. All you need is just to mute the error, by adding this code before exporting you config file

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// temporary work around to avoid 'ECONNREFUSED' error, preferably to find another solution
// remove the block when https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/5759 will be merged && released

let httpIndexFile = "node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js";
fs.readFile(httpIndexFile, "utf8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    let result = data.replace(/\(e.code === 'ECONNRESET'\)/g, "(e.code === 'ECONNRESET' || e.code === 'ECONNREFUSED')");
    console.log(`Patching ${httpIndexFile}`);
    fs.writeFileSync(httpIndexFile, result, "utf8");
});

let chromeFile = "node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js";
fs.readFile(chromeFile, "utf8", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    let result = data.replace(/new http.HttpClient\(url\)/g, "new http.HttpClient(url, new (require('http').Agent)({ keepAlive: true }))");
    console.log(`Patching ${chromeFile}`);
    fs.writeFileSync(chromeFile, result, "utf8");
});
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
exports.config = {
```

Again, this was another problem, but the tweak should work the same